# Getting interface NAME from java

Tags: java, networking, centos, network-interface

My OS is CentOS 6. In my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file, I have specified the network interface `"NAME"` to `"foo"` (let's suppose).

`NAME=foo`

I want to be able to get that interface  `"NAME"` from java. I tried the following, without a result:

```
     for (Enumeration nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); nis.hasMoreElements();) {
         NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
     System.out.println(ni.getDisplayName() + " " + ni.getName());
     }
```

It displays the same thing:

`eth0 eth0`

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to get the value of `NAME`, property of a network interface, in java?

Thanks.

NOTE: When specify `NAME=foo`, then the name of that interface in the network panel placed on the up right corner of the screen is `foo`.

Comment: Did you try restarting networking after setting the network interface's name to a new value?

Comment: @KohányiRóbert Yes. But getName() and getDisplayName() methods of NetworkInterface class, from what I see, do not have anything with NAME property.

Comment: Yeah, the methods probably didn't specify if they return _stuff_ form a *nix specific configuration file's key value or not, because they try to be independent. Also, by definition `NetworkInterface.getName()` will / should return the name of a _network interface_. In your case, I guess, `NAME` isn't your network interface's name, but a label you tagged `eth0` with, which is your _real_ network interface, and its _real_ name. (Although I'm not a *nix expert and I don't have enough knowledge on network interfaces and their names in particular.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have changed the NIC name properly, please check the following link [CentOS NIC name change](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=10434)

Comment: I didn't refer to ethN name. I refer to NAME property from ifcfg-ethN file. How can I access it from java? That's my problem.